# form.is_valid() always return false

Tags: javascript, python, html, css, datatable

my function update doesn´t work, the form.is_valid always return false and don't change the values in data-table and data base (SQLite), i try to replace the view but it's the same. i try to found many solutions for example required method or  change the order from the view.
this is the views:

```
def update(request, nSerie):  
    eequiposs = Equipos.objects.get(nSerie=nSerie)  
    form = EquiposForm( instance = eequiposs)  
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = EquiposForm(request.POST, instance = eequiposs)  
        if form.is_valid():  
            try:  
                form.save()  
                return redirect('/')  
            except:  
                pass
    else:
          
        form = EquiposForm()  
    return render(request,'show.html',{'form':form})
```

this the urls:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from app import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('',views.index, name='index'),
    path('addnew',views.addnew, name='addnew'),
    path('edit/<str:nSerie>',views.edit, name='edit'),
    path('update/<str:nSerie>',views.update, name='update'),
    path('delete/<str:nSerie>',views.destroy, name='destroy' )
]
```

and this is te html

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
  
{% block title %}Editar Equipo{% endblock title %}
  
{% block content %}
<div class="col">
    <form method="POST" class="post-form" action="/update/{{eequiposs.nSerie}}">
    {% csrf_token %}  
    <div class="container">   
        <div class="col">  
            <h3>Detalles del equipo</h3>  
        </div> 
        <div class="mb-3">
            <label>N° Serie:</label> 
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="nSerie" id="id_nSerie" required maxlength="25" value="{{eequiposs.nSerie}}" />
            {{ form.nSerie.errors }}
        </div> 
        <div class="mb-3">
            <label>Marca:</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="marca" id="id_marca" required maxlength="20" value="{{eequiposs.marca}}" />
        </div> 
        <div class="mb-3">
            <label>Modelo:</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="tipo" id="id_tipo" required maxlength="30" value="{{eequiposs.tipo}}" />
        </div> 
        <div class="mb-3">
            <label>Reponsable Anterior:</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="respAnterior" id="id_respAnterior" required maxlength="30" value="{{eequiposs.respAnterior}}" />
        </div> 
        <div class="mb-3">
            <label>Etiqueta:</label> 
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="etiqueta" id="id_etiqueta" required maxlength="8" value="{{eequiposs.etiqueta}}" />
        </div>
        <div class="mb-3">
            <label>Oficina:</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="oficina" id="id_oficina" required maxlength="20" value="{{eequiposs.oficina}}" />
        </div>
        <div class="mb-3"> 
            <label>Estado:</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="estado" id="id_estado" required maxlength="20" value="{{eequiposs.estado}}" />
        </div>
        <div class="mb-3">
            <label>Observaciones:</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="observaciones" id="id_observaciones" required maxlength="60" value="{{eequiposs.observaciones}}" />
        </div>
        <div class="mb-3">
            <label>Nuevo Responsable:</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="nuevoResp" id="id_nuevoResp" required maxlength="30" value="{{eequiposs.nuevoResp}}" />
        </div>
        <div class="mb-3">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-lg" >Editar</button>
        </div> 
    </div>  
    </form>  
{% endblock content %}
```

form:

```
class EquiposForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Equipos
        fields = ['nSerie', 'marca', 'tipo', 'modelo','respAnterior','etiqueta','oficina','estado','observaciones','nuevoResp']
        widgets = {'nSerie': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
        'marca': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
        'tipo': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control',}),
        'modelo': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
        'respAnterior': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
        'etiqueta': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
        'oficina': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
        'estado': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
        'observaciones': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
        'nuevoResp': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
        }
```

i try to change the html but doesn't work

Comment: Update the html so it displays **all** the possible form errors, instead of only `form.nSerie.errors`.

Comment: Also why is this tagged javascript?